# Unreliable font requests

Tags: css, fonts

I have a CSS file that loads two fonts into my webpage. Half of the time it works just fine, and half of the time the font requests fail with `failed to decode downloaded font`.

CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'oswald';
  src: local('Oswald Regular'),
       url(../fnt/font-oswald/Zm9udA_b3N3YWxk.eot);
  src: url(../fnt/font-oswald/Zm9udA_b3N3YWxk.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(../fnt/font-oswald/Zm9udA_b3N3YWxk.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(../fnt/font-oswald/Zm9udA_b3N3YWxk.woff) format('woff'),
       url(../fnt/font-oswald/Zm9udA_b3N3YWxk.ttf) format('truetype'),
       url(../fnt/font-oswald/Zm9udA_b3N3YWxk.svg#oswald) format('svg');
  font-weight:400;
  font-style:normal;
}
@font-face{
  font-family:'icon-general';
  src: url(../fnt/icon-general/aWNvbg_Z2VuZXJhbA.eot);
  src: url(../fnt/icon-general/aWNvbg_Z2VuZXJhbA.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(../fnt/icon-general/aWNvbg_Z2VuZXJhbA.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(../fnt/icon-general/aWNvbg_Z2VuZXJhbA.woff) format('woff'),
       url(../fnt/icon-general/aWNvbg_Z2VuZXJhbA.ttf) format('truetype'),
       url(../fnt/icon-general/aWNvbg_Z2VuZXJhbA.svg#icon-general) format('svg');
  font-weight:400;
  font-style:normal;
}
```

Oswald use

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-family:oswald}
```

Icon-general use

```
[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: 'icon-general';
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
}
```

CSS linking in HTML file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/static.css">
```

Note that: it might be useful to know that no `Content-Type` headers are set in the font requests, that may be why there is trouble decoding the files.

Comment: Where did the font come from and did you convert it to a web font using something like font squirrel tool?

Comment: The first font was from Google fonts, and the second generated by fontastic.me. The Google font was converted to web fonts and both had there ttf variation converted to woff2 by online sources.

Comment: Can you post the html and css you're running with this? Such as how and on what html you're loading the font. I do notice your icon-general font doesn't have the source: local declaration...

Comment: I am running HTML5, I will post more information shortly

Comment: step 1: reduce the possible complexity here. All browsers support WOFF, so you don't need all those other formats (you would have needed them three years ago, but not anymore), and some of them have been abandoned already (like eot and svg; EOT because IE8- have been abandoned by MS earlier this year, and SVG because everyone recognised it was a terrible idea and moved on to WOFF instead). That simplification alone may already solve your problem. If not, you have a more reliably reproducible error case.